# Can I change my keybindings to fly this way in BF1?

Tags: pc, battlefield-1

Is there a way in settings to make it so I don't have to continually move the mouse up/down if I want to move my plane up/down?
Rather, I want to move my mouse up a little, and the throttle would increase or decrease based on where I moved my mouse, and to throttle back, I would move my mouse back to the center.